Kubernetes Ingress Not Routing Traffic to Services Until Adding a Catch-All Rule
I'm working on a Kubernetes cluster with an NGINX Ingress controller. I have an Ingress resource configured to route traffic based on specific hostnames to their respective services.
Here’s my initial Ingress configuration:

kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: host1.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service1
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: host2.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service2
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - host1.example.com
        - host2.example.com
      secretName: tls-cert

However, the Ingress wasn’t routing the traffic correctly. After some troubleshooting, I added a catch-all rule without specifying a host:
   - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service2
                port:
                  number: 80

Now, the routing works perfectly for both the specified hosts and any other incoming traffic.
My question is:

Why did adding this catch-all rule fix the issue?
Shouldn't the Ingress have routed traffic based on the specific host rules without needing a catch-all rule?

Additional Info:
Kubernetes version: v1.29.2
Ingress Controller: NGINX
Services service1 and service2 are both ClusterIP services running on port 80.
DNS records for host1.example.com and host2.example.com are correctly configured.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

The main issue with the user's original Ingress configuration is likely due to the lack of a root path rule ("/") without specifying a host in the Ingress.
This can cause the NGINX Ingress controller to not properly handle requests, especially when no specific hostname matches the incoming request.
Kubernetes Ingress allows external access to your internal services by any path. It lets you use the same Load Balancer for multiple applications. An ALB rule was created based on the path,
so the path / with pathType: Prefix was added:
paths:
         - path: /
           pathType: Prefix

The added catch-all rule at the end ensures that if no host matches, the request is still routed to a service (in this case, service2), rather than hitting the default backend or failing to route.
Adding this catch-all rule resolves the issue because Ingress rules are processed in the order they are listed. If a request doesn’t match any of the specified hostnames, it will not be routed by those rules.
- host: host1.example.com

http:

paths:

- path: /

backend:

serviceName: "Helllo"

servicePort: 9080

In  above case, the issue was due to an ALB rule that was created based on the path.
Kubernetes Ingress should ideally route traffic based on specific host rules without needing a catch-all rule. However, Ingress rules are designed to match traffic based on both hostname and path. Each rule specifies which hostname and path should be handled by which backend service.
I used this SO and the Kubernetes Ingress catch-all article for code reference.


For more details, refer to these links:

use Kubernetes ingress for routing HTTP traffic

Kubernetes Ingress Controller Guide



I'm sharing my ingress configuration that's currently working for me. The issue is that removing the catch-all rule stops all routing. With the current config, I can access the example-welcome service via the load balancer's external IP, which makes sense due to the catch-all rule, but I don't want this behavior.

I don't want my services exposed via the external load balancer IP.
The ingress should work without the catch-all rule.

Any suggestions?
